# a call to query consoleText returns with HttpStatus 100 - how to deal with that?

Tags: rest, jenkins

I am working on a program than launches Jenkins jobs using the REST API. After the job has completed, I'd like to get its log, so I call `http://jenkins.domain.com/job/my_job_name/#/consoleText` in my code.

In 75% of the cases that works and I get the text in return. But there a some cases where it comes back with HttpStatus 100 and no text. (Opening the URL with the browser then shows the text, so clearly there is something to return.)  *(I haven't found any pattern that would explain it, like "exceptionally large log" or so.)*

I found no documentation about calls returning 100 and have no idea how to proceed. Simple repeating the call gives the same result. So how can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly "exceptionally large" **was** the answer. This caused a timeout (followed by some inappropriate handling) in the library that I used to handle the HttpGet. (Fortunately it was fixed very quickly.)